# I can't mv a directory "permission denied" yet I already did "chmod -R a+rwX ."

Tags: permission, filesystem

I need to move a folder, and for some reason I can't:

```
mv old_name new_name
mv: rename old_name/ to new_name: Permission denied
```

I already did

```
chmod -R a+rwX .
```

so all folders, subfolders, and files seem to have appropriate permissions.

One possibility is that a file or folder is locked by a process.  But, I don't seem to have any apps running, and I checked my Daemons with Launchcontrol, and

```
lsof | grep old_name
```

doesn't show any files open.

I really need to rename the folder. How can I do it?  Should I try safe mode? How can I determine what's locking the folder and stopping it from being renamed?

Thanks for any insight anyone can provide!

Comment: Where is it? What's it called? What are the perms on the enclosing folder/drive?

Comment: what does `ls -Old old_name` show? Is this directory mark immutable (`uchg`)?

Comment: It's in ~myusername/Dropbox (MyCompanyName)/   Permissions on enclosing folder/drive are fine, I can rename other folders in the directory. 

Dropbox isn't running.  Dropbox is trying to rename the folder, because Dropbox decided to restructure their business system folder structure. I'm trying to figure out why Dropbox can't mv the folder, and it turns out I can't mv it either.

Comment: `ls -Old old_name/
drwxrwxrwx@ 17 jabraham  staff  - 544  2 Jul 15:00 old_name/`

Comment: It's so weird I really can't find any process or permission that's blocking the rename. I guess I resort to safe mode to see if that works.

Comment: You have to have permissions on the containing directory, not on the object you're trying to rename.

Comment: Yes @MarcWilson I seem to have all the right permissions.  I can rename other folders in the same directory.

Comment: Looks like there's extended attributes: what does `ls -Old@e old_name` show?

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what caused the problem. But, I was able to fix it:

```
mkdir old_name_2
cd old_name
mv * ../old_name_2
mv .* ../old_name_2
cd ..
sudo rmdir old_name
mv old_name_2 old_name
```

Now I (or Dropbox) can successfully

```
mv old_name new_name
```

For some really weird reason the directory could not be renamed, but it could be deleted once it was empty. And, a new directory with the old name could be created and all the stuff moved into it, so that it all looks the same, ready for modification by Dropbox.

(The root of the problem was the Dropbox decided to 'upgrade' the structure of their directories, so the Dropbox app needed to be enabled to rename folders, otherwise their system would break entirely...)